# is there any DSL for streams/iterators?

Tags: java, scala, iterator, time-series, dsl

I wonder (and nearly become desperate) if there is any worked out DSL for streams/iterators on ordered series of objects?

The sources are ordered streams of id,time,key,value instances and the requirement is to join and analyse those streams. This has to be done by collecting combinations of keys and applying metrics to values within certain (defineable) time-constraints (count distinct keys or sum values within a day, within same second ..). There are some DSL, that work on timeseries (ESP), but mostly using relatively simple time-windows and they do not seem to be able to handle the order/join by id,time etc (and in consequence the computation of combinations by id).

What I have to do is something like "compute the combinations of A and (B or C), count distinct D within same second, sum E with same id"

The results should contain all available combinations of A, (B or C) with the count of distinct values for key D that are in the same second with A, (B or C) for each distinct id and the sum of the values for key E for each id (which is the sum over all values of E for ids havin A, (B or C).

not an easy question. I'm just looking for maybe helpful, already thought out DSL for such problems. I do not think SQL will make it.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Once Slick has type providers, you might have a hope of implementing it that way. If you want freedom to create an arbitrary and optimized query grammar, an internal DSL is likely to be overly restrictive.

Comment: Are you looking for a DSL for Complex Event Processing (CEP)? Do you want it to be based on a persistence layer (DB or memory based) or as a Collection based API?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can't find such methods because `streams` and `iterators` are not intended to contain ordered data (however they can). As result if you can't rely on sorted data inside there is no need in such methods, because you will need to read all data from stream/iterator thus they will loose their main purpose as a data structure. So why not to use list?